# Same command, different result on Mac vs Centos

Tags: bash, macos, centos

I use this command to drain any active dataflow job:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs list --project=myProjectId --status=active --uri | awk -F/ '{print $NF}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty gcloud dataflow jobs drain --project=myProjectId --region=europe-west4
```

and it works for me both on my Mac (bash) and Centos docker machine.

Breaking down that command:

Command:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs list --project=myProjectId --status=active --uri
```

Result:

```
https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/myProjectId/locations/europe-west4/jobs/2020-08-09_12345
```

Command:

```
awk -F/ '{print $NF}'
```

will give me the job ID = 2020-08-09_12345 so i can drain it with :

```
xargs --no-run-if-empty gcloud dataflow jobs drain --project=myProjectId --region=europe-west4
```

---

All is good until I decided to filter the job id by job name

My new command:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs list --project=myProjectId --status=active \
| grep "jobName" | awk '{print $1}' \
| xargs -E --no-run-if-empty gcloud dataflow jobs drain --project=myprojectId --region=europe-west4
```

Breaking down the command:
Command:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs list --project=myProjectId --status=active
```

Result:

```
JOB_ID            NAME               TYPE       CREATION_TIME        STATE    REGION
2020-08-09_12345  jobName_123456789  Streaming  2020-08-09 10:57:57  Running  europe-west4
```

Chained command :

```
grep "jobName" | awk '{print $1}'
```

will still give me the job ID = 2020-08-09_12345

This command works fine for me on my Mac (Iterm2), but when running it on Centos docker machine, it throws this error :

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataflow.jobs.drain) argument JOB_ID [JOB_ID ...]: Must be specified.
Usage: gcloud dataflow jobs drain JOB_ID [JOB_ID ...] [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --help | --region
```

Can someone help me to point out where did I do wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: The error message implies that you used `jobs drain` instead of `jobs list`. Check your command again.

Comment: `grep "jobName" | awk '{print $1}'` is a bit of an anti-pattern, you can use `awk '/jobName/ {print $1}'`

Comment: I think you should check out gcloud's `--format` option. Seems to me that you should be able to run something like: 
`gcloud dataflow jobs list --project=myProjectId --status=active --format="value(jobId)" | while read -r job; do gcloud dataflow jobs drain $job; done`